# other menu in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I use joomla 2.5, I create a menu to put inside a module.

In the *index* of my template I have this

```
 <div id="wrapper-header-left" class="column grid_6">
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('mod_imagenMenu')): ?>
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_imagenMenu" style="none"/>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('mod_izquierdo')): ?>
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_izquierdo" style="none"/>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                        <div id="wrapper-header-right" class="column grid_10">
                            <?php if ($this->countModules('mod_extranet')): ?>
                                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_extranet" style="none"/>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div id="Menu_Principal">
                                <ul class="menu">
                                    <?php if ($this->countModules('mod_menuPrincipal')): ?>
                                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_menuPrincipal" style="none"/>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

`mod_izquierdo` inside this module I want to show a menu

In the `default.php` file of this module I call the menu

```
<div class="conozca">
    <p>Conozca más sobre Arq/p>
        <ul>

            <!--<li><a href="#">¿Cómo adquirir Arq?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">¿Qué equipos componen Arq?</a></li> -->
        </ul>   
</div>
```

But when I render the page I don't see the menu, if I put this line

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_ar_menu" style="none"/>
```

in the index I show the menu duplicate.

What is my error, can I put the menu inside the module?

Comment: where is your `mod_ar_menu` module is shown?

Comment: Hi @Tornado I change my file  and now  I have this mod_arq_menu(Public in mod_arquero), and it is ok, but how show the menu inside de <div id="arMenu">

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to show your `mod_arq` module inside the `<div id="arMenu">` means in another module.

Comment: ok @Tornado I explain better sorry. I have a module mod_arq that show only in one page. By other hand I have a menu call "Arq" arq(Public in mod_arquero), ok now in default.php in the module_arq I have a div, I want the menu inside the div, to do this I have this line <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mod_arquero" style="none"/> But I see the menu outside :/ thanks for your help I appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be calling specific modules in your template like that, it is going to make your life a lot harder if you ever have to make changes. First thing you need to understand is that the index.php in your template should only contain module positions. It should look more like this -

```
<div id="wrapper-body" class="row">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="none"/>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <div id="content" class="column grid_16">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top-middle" style="none"/>
        <jdoc:include type="component" />
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom-middle" style="none"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left-column" style="none"/>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right-column" style="none"/>
        <div class="clr"></div>

        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom" style="none"/>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
```

This page is supposed to be used to create the basic structure of the site. If you want to really get fancy, you would make each module position collapsible so that any position not being used does on a particular page does no output any code. That would look something like this -

```
        <?php if ($this->countModules('top')) : ?>
        <div id="top"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="none" /></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Once you have your positions worked out, you can now create instances of modules and assign them to the position you want them to display in as well as the page or pages you want it to display on. In the Extensions Menu, click the Module Manager link. There you will create new modules. In the module parameters there is a selection for which module position you want to display the module in. Below that, you can also select which menu items you want the module to display on. You can select All, None, Exclude Selection, or Only on Selection.

Doing it this way makes it very easy to manage your modules. It allows you to put more than one module in a particular position, then select the order they are in within that position. For example you could put a menu module, login module, and image rotator module all in the left column. It also makes you code a lot cleaner since you are not having to call a module within a module like you are trying to do. That is only going to make your site hard to manage and it will slow down performance.

Comment: thanks @BrentFriar for you good advised, but I still have the same problem. First I create my menu with two links to simple article I want to show this menu in "mod_izquierdo" position  this only show in the fist page so In the Extensions Menu, click the Module Manager link. There you will create new modules, select menu in a pop up and finally Menu1 (Public in mod_izquierdo) it show me the link but outside of div. Is my default.php file correct?

Comment: Do you have a link to the site? It sounds like you may have an error in your HTML somewhere.